# MIPS does not recognize ascii symbols.

Tags: ascii, mips

I am trying to get an input from user and compare it with (+ , - , *, /, =) and then make the corresponding arithmetic operation. But Mips cant figure out each symbol.it continues loop2 for ever.... I give a part of code... any idea what' s wrong? (Registers are all correct)

```
.data
op1: .asciiz "+" 
op2: .asciiz "-"
op3: .asciiz "*"
op4: .asciiz "/"
op5: .asciiz "%"
op6: .asciiz "="

.text

loop2 :

li $v0, 4          
la $a0, operator              #Εμφάνισε μήνυμα "Τελεστής:"
syscall 


addi $v0, $zero, 5            #Διάβασε τον τελεστή
syscall


move $s2 , $v0                #Βάλε τον τελεστή στον καταχωρητή $s2


#---------------------------------


sw $t1 ,op1                   #Αν ο τελεστής είναι '+'
beq  $s2, $t1, ADDITION


ADDITION:

li $v0, 4                     #Εμφάνισε μήνυμα "Αριθμός:"
la $a0, number               
syscall            


addi $v0, $zero, 5            #Διάβασε τον αριθμό
syscall

move $s3 , $v0                #βάλε τον αριθμό στον καταχωρητή $s3 

add $s4 , $s1 , $s3           # Πράξη πρόσθεσης των αριθμών.Το αποτέλεσμα αποθηκεύεται στον $s4

j loop2                       #Εφόσον δεν ήταν "=" ο τελεστής, ζήτα τον επόμενο τελεστή
```

Comment: `sw $t1 ,op1` Why would you use a store operation here? (btw, when posting code, please translate any comments to english)

Comment: which other operation i could use for string? (sorry i saw it lately)

Comment: sw $t1 ,op1                   #Αν ο τελεστής είναι '+'
beq  $s2, $t1, ADDITION

Comment: the problem is tha cant understand when user input is + e.t.c

Comment: `sw` means Store Word, i.e. write the value of a 32-bit register to memory. I don't know what you wanted to do because I don't know greek, but if you wanted to load a character from `op1` you should use `lb` or `lbu`.

Comment: i have tried it,but nothing... i want to do exactly what i say on the previous comment. I cant think of anything else to do....

Comment: Well, you're using system call 5, which is `read_integer`. You shouldn't expect it to handle things other than numbers in any meaningful way.

Comment: i just want to compare a string like "=" with user input which is like =

Comment: oh my gooooddddd you are right!!! thank you so much!!!!!!!!

Comment: ok i will change the number and i will make the ascii like "=\n" right?